# How to get the name of a reference class?

Tags: r, oop, reference-class

For instance, is there some function `getName` that allows me to do:

```
> TestA <- setRefClass("TestA")
> getName(TestA())
[1] "TestA"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe simply check its class:

```
class(TestA())
```